# Problem entering value in <input> even using multiple event codes and only works with error

Tags: javascript

first sorry my bad english, i am using google translator.
I have a following input:

```
input spellcheck="false" type="text" tabindex="-1" class="jhsOUI" value="some text"
```

this entry has an event of pressing "Enter" and "blur" and "onChange".
I know that using jQuery, I just need the following command to enter the value I want for `<input>`:

```
$('input.jhsOUI').val(text);
```

I've tried everything, even the following code:

```
var text= text;

var e = $.Event( "keypress", { which: 13 } );

$('input.jhsOUI')[0].click();

$('input.jhsOUI').focus();

$('input.jhsOUI').val(text);

$('input.jhsOUI.').change();

$('input.jhsOUI').trigger(e);

$('input.jhsOUI').blur();
```

and when I leave any error in the middle of the code, the input value is updated to what I want. example:

```
var text= text;

$('input.jhsOUI').val(text);

error;
```

ready with this "error" script because i didn't declare the string and the value is changed, i would like to know if there is a way to solve this problem without me having a code crashing and stopping like this?

Comment: Hi Bruno. It'd be really helpful for others viewing this question if you could make a quick working example to help with debugging.

Comment: You wire up events like this: $( "#target" ).keypress(function() {
  console.log( "Handler for .keypress() called." );
});

Comment: CM, I did the (#targed) test, the event is called, but it does not change the value of <input> just with the error, and justDan which example for debug? practically only has this problem in the script.